# Template constructor in a class template

Tags: c++

I have an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T>
struct A{
    A([[maybe_unused]]T t){std::cout<<"contructor 1";}
    template<typename X>
    A([[maybe_unused]]X x1,[[maybe_unused]]X x2){
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
        std::cout<<std::is_same_v<decltype(x1),int><<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"contructor 2"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<x1<<" "<<x2<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int ax=3;
    [[maybe_unused]]A<char> a(ax,ax);
}
```

which will print out

```
false
contructor 2
3 3
```

However I cant understand why should I have a class constructor template. And no matter what the class template type is, the result is unchanged. Can anyone explain the reason of this concept.

Answer (score 0):

This code is surely only for learning purposes, so I assume you ask in general what kind of use case there is for a templated constructor inside a templated class.

One good example of this pattern appears in the common implementation for type-erasure without inheritance. See e.g. here:

[C++ Techniques: Type-Erasure vs. Pure Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309927/c-techniques-type-erasure-vs-pure-polymorphism)

It's quite an advanced pattern, but very interesting.

BTW - in your specific case you wrote that

> no matter what the class template type is, the result is unchanged

But it will change if you change the type of ax e.g. to short:

```
short ax = 3;
```

because the prints compare the argument type (and not the class template type) to `int`.